# Framelayout not appearing top of RecyclerView in constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I am new at this android programming.

I am trying to have a framelayout and a textview on top of a recycler view (which is part of a ConstraintLayout, which I needed to position the FAB on the bottom right of the screen) but it doesn't seem to appear.

Some help and advice of why this is happening and what should be done appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    tools:context="com.testapp.testapp.HomeActivity">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/org_store_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingRight="12dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/order_ID"
                style="@style/AppTheme.Subheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:visibility="visible"
                tools:text="Order #: 0001123" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_orders"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_orders"

        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/recycler_orders"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_shadow" />

    <!-- Empty list (pizza guy) view ... havent tested empty view-->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="gone">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/AppTheme.PizzaGuy"
            android:contentDescription="@string/message_no_results"
            android:src="@drawable/pizza_monster" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/AppTheme.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/message_no_results"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_300" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recycler_orders"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/recycler_orders"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_addnew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please read about constraint layout and it's attributes (https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-the-new-android-constraintlayout-eed37fe8d8f1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good thing about ConstraintLayout is that it is so powerfull you don't need to use nested layouts anymore. So, in your case, the nested FrameLayout and the nested ConstraintLayout are not needed.

You can, for example, specify a background and padding directly on your order_ID TextView, and you can get rid of your FrameLayout. Also, everything inside the view_empty can be put directly as child of the main ContraintLayout. What is missing in your layout are constraints! ConstraintLayout needs constraints to know where to draw its children, but you haven't provided any! This means that, since the layout does not know where to draw things, everything will be at the left top corner of the layout itself.

One last thing: ConstraintLayout works perfectly with ltr and rtl languages. For this reason, it is better to use marginStart and marginEnd, and not marginLeft and marginRight.

Comment: Thanks - yes I downloaded the project on Google's tutorial of ConstraintLayout(https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/) that helped me a lot.